# jQuery mouseenter is fired up multiple times?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I am testing a chrome extension for youtube, but I have a problem where mouseenter is fired up multiple times.

This is what I have for a simple mouse enter on the thumbnails:

```
$( "body" ).on('mouseenter', '#thumbnail', function() {
    console.log('click');
});
```

Now once the page loads up and I hover on any thumbnail, it will be triggered just once and the click text will be shown inside the console once per action.

The problem begins when I browse to a different youtube section, lets say -  trending. Now If I hover on the thumbnail again in the trending page, the click text will appear 3 times in the console per single action. If I browse back to the main page again, it will double or sometimes tripple the output per single on hover action.

I have tried .off method but that made no difference. Where could be the problem?

This is my js to load the jquery and the functions js to the website:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId , info) {
  if (info.status === 'complete') {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        file: 'jquery-3.2.1.min.js'
    });
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        file: 'payload.js'
    });
  }
});
```

Could it be that the executeScript is loaded every time youtube website loads a different page inside?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: A simple way to test to see if your *payload.js* is loading multiple times in the same context, would be to just have an unconditional `console.log()` at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 0):

You only need .off when for example the content of your page is changed dynamically. If the changed content has the same element (e.g. same id) you have bounded - depends on your onContentChange event - two different .on events on that content. So when you change for example a content dynamically you have to run .off before you change the content. Otherwise you will run into problems.
A typically problem is when you are loading content with ajax and you assign some .on events but never run .off.

To your problem, have you tried a simple console.log inside of your addListener to check whether you execute your script multiple times or not?

Comment: Yes, just tested..Thats where the problem is.. the 'chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener' will be loaded twice every single tab change on youtube website which will pile up the listeners..

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve, but maybe it helps to define a global variable like _isInit = true/false_ and test against this on every addListeneder to prevent multiple loadings

Comment: Well I want to get rid of this issue as this multiple listeners will cause various problems for me. The global variable will not make any difference as It will not know when the page was refreshed and when it was just an ajax request? I think it was a bug with chrome which was marked as fixed. Still cant find a solution

Comment: Simply add a check for info.url - it occurs just once per update.

Answer (score -1):

Ok it seems that the issue was with my manifest.. I changed my manifest multiple times but this time worked for some reason.

I removed both `executeScript` functions fomr the payload.js and loaded content scripts from the manifest:

```
 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js","payload.js"]
    }
  ],
```

Now it works like a charm..

Comment: You have not included your *manifest.json* in the question. Thus, there is no way for anyone to know that this actually answers the question. We would have to be psychic to be able to know this is the answer.

Comment: That was because I was pretty certain it was not the manifest causing the problem, therefore I have not included it. This solution solved my problem, so It will be marked as accepted answer

Comment: I'm not saying that your answer is wrong. I'm saying that your question is bad because it does not contain a [mcve]. In addition, it does not say why you are using `tabs.executeScript()` to inject instead of a *manifest.json* `content_scripts` entry, so that we can determine that using a `content_scripts` entry is even a possible solution for your issue. Each of those independently makes your answer bad because it relies on information not contained in the question. Although, admittedly, we can certainly guess, with a high confidence, as to what the problem is, but we should not need to guess.

Comment: To be explicit: I down-voted both your question & answer, and voted to close your question as being off-topic dues to lacking a [mcve] (see [#1 in the on-topic page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). If you put your *manifest.json* in the question and describe why you chose to use `tabs.executeScript()` instead of a `content_scripts` entry (i.e. so we can understand that using a `content_scripts` entry is an acceptable possibility), then I will remove my down-votes and retract my close vote. If you do so, please ping me by including `@Makyen` in a comment here or on your question.

Comment: Calm down, I already answered my own question, you can close it down if it makes you feel any better. I asked the way I did because I have 0 experience in chrome extension dev, therefore I had no idea which files are necessary to include. I always try to include basic information so it will make a short question and easier to read or understand.

Comment: I'm calm. My actions (voting) and statements are not personal. They only reflect my opinion of your question and answer. My opinion of them can easily be changed, by adding the information I've mentioned. Questions and answers on Stack Exchange don't exist just for the person who asked the question. They also exist, even primarily exist, for the other people who find the question in the future, while looking for a solution to a problem they have. It's good that you answered your own question. [Answering your own question is encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).